# TYPO3 extension how to limit findAll (best practise)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

Hi what is the best practise to limit the result of findAll in TYPO3?

I want to do it in controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean using an Extbase repository? (Have added extbase tag, but it would be helpful to add some more information to your question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the query in the controller as well:

```
$this->myRepository->findAll()->getQuery()->setLimit(4)->execute();
```

Comment: Incidentally that's exactly what the [paginate viewhelper/controller does](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/d7ce554/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Widget/Controller/PaginateController.php#L172-L180).

Answer (score 1):

Better do it in repository by overriding `findAll()` and `setLimit()` for the query. Or use the viewHelper `<f:widget.paginate ...>` in template.

Comment: It's not possible to use `findAll` with parameters as the `RepositoryInterface` is forbidding that. This limitation can be circumvented by repository-properties that can be influenced by setter-functions, i.e. `setLimit()` or `setOffset()`. These properties can be used then inside `findAll()`with `$this->limit` or `$this->offset`.